# Sublime text 3 настройка сворачивания тегов html

Tags: sublime-text-3

В sublime text 3 сворачивание кода (code folding) действует, когда внутри тега есть не менее 2 вложенных элементов. Как настроить, чтобы тег можно было сворачивать, если он имеет хотя бы один вложенный элемент?

Comment: Когда сворачиваешь сочетаниями клавиш, это правило не учитывается. Откройте key bindings и выставьте удобные для вас комбинации под эти задачи (или пользуйтесь стандартными `ctrl+shift+[`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

А такой вариант сворачивания кода вас не устраивает?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]